# SQL Write Values from Multiple Rows to Single Result

Tags: sql

I have a table that I need to pull data from, let's call it AUDITHISTORY. Every time a change is made it is written to this table like so:

`IDNum  FieldUpdated OldValue NewValue Updatetime`  
`1      urgency      Medium   High     DATETIME1`
`1      urgency      High     Medium   DATETIME2`
`2      urgency      Medium   High     DATETIME1`
`2      urgency      High     Medium   DATETIME2`

I'm trying to write a select statement to put the data like this:

`IDNum StartTime StopTime    Difference`
`1     DATETIME1 DATETIME2   DATETIME2-DATETIME1`
`2     DATETIME1 DATETIME2   DATETIME2-DATETIME1`

... for all events that appear within a given timeframe. I have a script that displays them in two rows per each "IDNUM" and I'm having trouble getting them to group correctly.

Comment: after you determine the business rules that make one record or the other go in a column, you basically join to the audit table twice, once with where conditions to get the first record and once with where conditions to get the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as DATETIME2 is always greater than DATETIME1, this should work;

```
SELECT IDNum, MIN(Updatetime) DATETIME1,
              MAX(Updatetime) DATETIME2,
              MAX(Updatetime) - MIN(Updatetime) Difference
FROM AUDITHISTORY
GROUP BY IDNum
```

The difference (ie result of subtracting two datetimes) isn't the same for all RDBMS', so you may want to use a more database specific method to get the format you like.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for!